# awk print between lines when "/" is part of the name

Tags: awk, string, printing, pattern-matching, slash

I need to print lines between those that contain a "/" in the name.
I tried with:

```
awk '/+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES/,/-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES/' $F > fil$F
```

and

```
awk '/+SOLUTION"/"ESTIMATES/,/-SOLUTION"/"ESTIMATES/' $F > fil$F
```

and

```
awk '/"{+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES}"/,/"{-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES}"/' $F > fil$F
```

but the error is always more or less the same like "unterminated string".

How can I print lines between those patterns?

Comment: [edit] your question to show sample input and expected output that cover all of your non-trivial cases so we can provide the best answer for you as there are many possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used inside an awk [regular expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04) constant, the forward slash character must be escaped to distinguish it from the surrounding delimiters. For example with GNU awk:

```
$ echo 'foo/bar was here' | gawk '/foo/bar/'
awk: cmd. line:2: /foo/bar/
awk: cmd. line:2:          ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

but

```
$ echo 'foo/bar was here' | gawk '/foo\/bar/'
foo/bar was here
```

As well, the `+` character has a special meaning in the Extended Regular Expression (ERE) dialect used by awk, and should be escaped if you want to match a literal plus character. So:

```
/\+SOLUTION\/ESTIMATES/,/-SOLUTION\/ESTIMATES/
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I used this suggestion and it really worked.                                              awk '/\+SOLUTION\/ESTIMATES/,/\-SOLUTION\/ESTIMATES/' $F > temp

Answer (score 2):

> How can I print lines between those patterns?

By replacing `/` with `\57` records between patterns (and records with those patterns) can be printed.

But please read [this before using range expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk).

```
$ echo 'foo/bar was here' | awk '/foo\57bar/'
foo/bar was here
```

Answer (score 2):

`/regex/` is short for `$0 ~  /regex/`, which you can also write `$0 ~ "regex"`, so besides [escaping the `/` by prefixing it with `\`](/a/762375) or [using `\octal` with the `/` character value (`\57` on ASCII-based systems, `\141` on EBCDIC-based systems for instance)](/a/762377), you can also do:

```
awk '$0 ~ "\\+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES", $0 ~ "-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES"' < "$F" > "fil$F"
```

Beware `+` is an extended regex operator, so needs escaped either as `\+` or `[+]`. As `\` also has a special meaning in the syntax of `"strings"`, it's better to double it so a `\` be passed to the regex engine. With some `awk` implementations, you can get away with just `"\+"` but not all.

Note that using redirection rather than passing the file path as argument is preferable when possible as `awk` would choke on values of `$F`  such as `-` or that contain `=` (or that start with `-` with older versions of busybox `awk`). You also forgot to quote that `$F` argument making it subject to split+glob. Quoting parameter expansions in targets of redirections is generally not needed except for the notable exceptions of ksh88 and the bash shell when not POSIX mode (the latter still widely used) so it's still a good habit to quote them there as well.

Here, instead of a regex match, you could do a substring search:

```
awk 'index($0, "+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES"), index($0, "-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES")' < "$F" > "$fil$F"
```

To print from the line that *is* exactly `+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES` to the one that *is* exactly `-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES` (or to the end of the input if not found):

```
awk '$0 == "+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES", $0 == "-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES"' < "$F" > "$fil$F"
```

Using `perl` gives more flexibility:

```
# regex, but with different delimiters (m@...@, m{...}...)
perl -ne 'print if m{\+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES} .. m{-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES}'
```

```
# regex but use \Q...\E regex quoting for anything inside to be taken literally:
perl -ne 'print if m{\Q+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES\E} .. m{-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES}'
```

```
# substring search with q(...) as strong quotes, same as '...' except
# easier to use inside shell '...' quotes.
perl -ne 'print if index($_, q(+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES)) >= 0 ..
                   index($_, q(-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES)) >= 0'
```

```
# string equality with eq
perl -lne 'print if $_ eq q(+SOLUTION/ESTIMATES) ..
                    $_ eq q(-SOLUTION/ESTIMATES)'
```